# Reliably getting and setting cursor/caret position in an editable div

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I'm building a simple online document editor. In this editor I want the text to be broken up into pages with each page being a contenteditable div.

I've come up with a basic algorithm for doing this. Essentially I check the div currently in focus to see if it has more words than the `WORDS_PER_PAGE` constant. If it does then take the last word of this page and put it at the beginning of the next page. Then you perform the same check on the next page, then the next page, etc until you've reached the end of the pages. A similiar check is performed when the key being pressed is the delete/backspace key.

Now this algorithm isn't perfect (each page will be a variable height depending on the lengths of the words) but it suits my needs just fine. The thing that's really screwing me around is setting the cursor position and getting the cursor position of these editable divs. All I want is a function `getCursor (element)` that will return the number of characters that the cursor is offset by and `setCursor (element, n)` that will set the cursor at n characters offset.

I don't give a crap about IE < 9 so I don't need a wonky workaround for it. I also can't use the Rangy library or any other library for that matter. I've tried messing around with the Range and Selection objects but I can't get anything going. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how I should attack this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true" onclick="alert(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset)">
```

Credit: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?702589-set-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div